# Are parameters evaluated in order when passed into a method?

Tags: c#

Are parameters evaluated in order when they passed into a method?

For Java it's always true, for C it isn't, but what is the answer for C#?

Sample

```
string.Format("byte1={0} byte2={1} byte3={2}", 
  getNextByte(), 
  getNextByte(), 
  getNextByte());

int pos=0;
byte[] arr=new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6};
byte getNextByte()
{
  return arr[pos++];  
}
```

This sample works, but is it only luck or a rule?

Comment: "Evaluated" is probably a more precise word than "accessed".

Comment: Btw, this question has been asked before.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, expressions passed as arguments to methods are always evaluated from left to right.

From the C# 4.0 Language Specification:

> **7.5.1.2 Run-time evaluation of argument lists**
>
> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (§7.5.4), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, ***from left to right***, [...]

Comment: I cant recall if this was a guarantee though. Do you remember or have a reference? Although one should never rely on this in any case :)

Comment: It's in the language spec; so yes this is a guarantee.

Comment: @leppie: The F# compiler depends on this behavior. `match dict.TryGetValue(key) with true, value -> ... | false, _ -> ...` compiles to `T value = default(T); Tuple<bool, T> tuple = new Tuple<bool, T>(dict.TryGetValue(key, out value), value); if (tuple.Item1) ...`.

Comment: Do you think this also applies to `params` arguments, which are basically syntactic sugar for array initialization?

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/arrays#array-initializers, it would appear so: _The expressions initialize array elements in increasing order, starting with the element at index zero._

Answer (score 30):

As others have pointed out, the language specification requires that parameters be evaluated in left-to-right order.

However, full disclosure, we accidentally and not on purpose introduced a couple of bugs in C# 4.0 where certain scenarios involving named arguments, optional parameters and ref-omitted parameters in calls to legacy COM objects, such that in those scenarios the side effects of arguments might not be evaluated in strictly left-to-right order. The analyzer that deals with the interactions between those features is complicated and it had some bugs.

I apologize for the errors; we hope to have them fixed in the next version.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I only use very simple parameters. I didn't expect any problems

Comment: @jeb: Indeed, almost no one will see these problems, which is why we did not catch them until it was too late to fix them. I note that in general, everything in C# is evaluated in left-to-right order. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/precedence/ for some more articles on this subject if it interests you.

Comment: @EricLippert you're my hero.

Comment: Broken link to the blog. I guess this is equivalent to what was linked? https://ericlippert.com/tag/precedence/

Comment: @relatively_random: Thanks for the note. Yes, MSFT keeps moving where my blog archive is. Eventually I will have all that content moved over to ericlippert.com.

Answer (score 3):

From the language specification:

> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation, the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right.