# Evaluation order of named parameters

Tags: c#, named-parameters, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are parameters evaluated in order when passed into a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359996/are-parameters-evaluated-in-order-when-passed-into-a-method)

Say I have

`void foo (int x, int y)`

and call it by:

`foo(y: genNum(), x: genNum())`

Does C# guarantee the evaluation order of x and y in this case?

Comment: Interesting theoretical question, but horrible idea to code this way in practice.  If you do, please include a link to this question for those that have to maintain the code in the future.

Comment: The question should be closed because, as pointed out in some answers, it's a duplicate of multiple questions.

Comment: Might not be a duplicate. My question specifically refers to the evaluation order of named argument passing. (The linked question doesn't obviously address my concern.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), arguments are always evaluated from left to right.  Unfortunately, there are a few bugs in some corner cases in C# 4.0.  See Eric Lippert's post at [Are parameters evaluated in order when passed into a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359996/are-parameters-evaluated-in-order-when-passed-into-a-method) for more details.

As an aside, this is probably bad practice.  If you want to guarantee the order that the arguments are evaluated, capture the result in a local variable first and then pass the results to the consuming method like:

```
int capturedY = genNum(); //It is important that Y is generated before X!
int capturedX = genNum();
foo(capturedX, capturedY);
```

I can't think of a good reason to not do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer, Just to show the side effect.*

```
public void Test()
{
    foo(y: genNum(), x: genNum());
}

int X=0;
int genNum()
{
    return ++X;
}

void foo(int x, int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the  [C# In Depth – Optional Parameters and Named Arguments](http://codebetter.com/2011/01/11/c-in-depth-optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-2/):

> ...The second of these calls reverses the order of the arguments, but
>   the result is still the same, because the arguments are matched up
>   with the parameters by name, not position.

In your case first will be executed `y` and after `x`, as it appears first (from the left) in the function declaration.

The fact that it's really ends up like a second parameter, is an implementation detail of C# compiler that implements named parameters.

Comment: "The result is still the same" is only true if the call to genNum contains no side-effects.

Comment: @PeteBaughman: Skeet, had no idea about the code written by OP, which is **very** dangerous and not productive.