# C# constructor chaining call order

Tags: c#, constructor, constructor-chaining

I have a class that can be created with data or with a binary reader (which it uses to deserialize it's data). It does additional initialization with the data, and since I don't want to duplicate that code, I want to chain the constructors. Right now this chaining looks like this:

```
public Item(string id, int count = 1) { /*...*/ }

public Item(BinaryReader reader) : this(reader.ReadString(), reader.ReadInt32()) { /*...*/ }
```

Is order in which these read calls are made deterministic?

**Clarification:** I was talking about the order in which `read.ReadString()` and `reader.ReadInt32()` are called.

Comment: [Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7360045/4137916). (Although I'd argue it's still rather bad form to rely on it -- a builder class that explicitly read sequentially would be a better idea.)

Comment: "Is order in which these read calls are made deterministic?" If you mean to ask if the `ReadString()` will always happen before the `ReadInt32` then yes.

Comment: Depends on the invocation order or the object creation style.

Comment: @JeroenMostert your comment is a perfect answer to my question, I suggest you resubmit it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact behavior of the order of evaluation when calling methods with multiple arguments is documented in the C# specification [Run-time evaluation of argument lists](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists) which states:

> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (Compile-time checking of dynamic overload resolution), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, **from left to right**, as follows:

So in your case the order will be:

- `reader.ReadString()`
- `reader.ReadInt32()`
- finally the other constructor will be called

Now, there are a couple of problem with this, mainly related to readability and exceptions.

The fact that **you** ask which call order is the correct one, the next programmer might have the same question. It would be better to refactor this into a different solution that doesn't come with a lot of questions attached.

Additionally, if you pass in a `null` `reader` you'll get a `NullReferenceException` instead of a `ArgumentNullException`, even if you should happen to validate this parameter not being `null` inside the constructor, simply because all this evaluation will happen before the constructor body executes. There are *hacks* to "fix" this but they are worse than the code you already have.

To refactor into a "better" solution (my opinion) you would create a factory method like this:

```
public static Item Create(BinaryReader reader)
{
    if (reader == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reader));
    // optional: handle exceptions from reader.ReadString and ReadInt32
    var s = reader.ReadString();
    var i = reader.ReadInt32();
    return new Item(s, i);
}
```